# Ler uma pagina da internet em uma variavel em VB

Tags: vb.net

Gente eu estou tentando ler uma  [página da internet](https://www.receitaws.com.br/v1/cnpj/27865757000102) e não estou conseguindo, quero que salve todo o conteúdo em uma variavel, o problema é que ela não tem nada de html nem xml, é somente texto, alguem saberia como fazer isso e tambem como procurar um texto nela?

Comment: Essa pagina seria um [JSON](http://www.json.org/json-pt.html)   certo ? Você teria que procurar como serializar um Json com `vb.net`

Comment: como eu poderia fazer isso?

Comment: Alguma das respostas lhe foi útil?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para serializar um [Json](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) em Vb.Net  [DataContractAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).

Primeiro você teria que criar um objeto para receber esse JSON, percebe que [o seu exemplo](https://www.receitaws.com.br/v1/cnpj/27865757000102) pussui objetos dentro do proprios Json, exemplo:

```
"atividades_secundarias": [
    {
      "text": "Reprodução de vídeo em qualquer suporte",
      "code": "18.30-0-02"
    },
```

Neste caso é um objeto chamado `atividades_secundarias` com dois atributos `text` e `code`. Que alias e uma `Array`

Para Serializar você pode fazer :

> 1.Você irá criar um método que receberá esse JSON e fara a deserialização

```
' VB.NET
Private Function DeserializarDataContractJsonSerializer() As List(Of SeuObjeto)
    Using Stream = New System.IO.FileStream(JsonQueVocêPassa, System.IO.FileMode.Open)
        Dim Serializer = New System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(GetType(List(Of Pedido)))
        Return DirectCast(Serializer.ReadObject(Stream), List(Of SeuObjeto))
    End Using
End Function
```

`JsonQueVocêPassa =` https://www.receitaws.com.br/v1/cnpj/27865757000102

`SeuObjeto =` Objeto que você cria coma  estrutura do Json que você esta tentando serializar.

Neste exemplo esta lendo um Json de um arquivo usando o e montando o objeto.

Caso queria alguns exemplos tem no site da [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb412179(v=vs.110).aspx) e também esse 
[Tutorial](http://www.andrealveslima.com.br/blog/index.php/2016/12/14/serializando-e-desserializando-json-com-c-e-vb-net/)

Comment: espera, eu copiaria a função no meu código e como eu chamaria ela? E ele retorna como?

Comment: Então, esse é um exemplo, você pode usar esse exemplo de base e tentar implementar para o seu caso, no seu a diferença seria que não esta deserializando apartir de uma arquivo, e sim apartir desse link, que pode ser uma `API REST`, tenta entrar nesses links que te mandei e veja o que você não entende.

Comment: E porque mutias vezes falta algum conhecimento sobre  `JSON `ou  como funciona esse retorna que você esta recebendo, ai fica dificil para você entender e fazer certo.

Answer (score 1):

> Pegar o Json

Na variável json você tera o objeto json obtido a partir da URL.

```
   Dim json As String = New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("https://www.receitaws.com.br/v1/cnpj/27865757000102")
```

> Converter Json para Xml

-Baixe a dll NewtonSoft:
http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

-Utilize a dll NewtonSoft

```
Dim doc As XmlDocument = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json, "root")
```